# How to add new shape to gojs floor planner palette

Tags: gojs

am playing with gojs exactly in floor planner as this image :
[image: Floor Planner]

My question is how to add new custom shape to the Palettes section in the left so i can use it like rounded table with two or four chairs, after i checking the code i found the part that responsible to draw them as the following:

```
// Node Data Array for Furniture Palette
FURNITURE_NODE_DATA_ARRAY = [
              {
                  category: "MultiPurposeNode",
                  key: "MultiPurposeNode",
                  caption: "Multi Purpose Node",
                  color: "#ffffff",
                  stroke: '#000000',
                  name: "Writable Node",
                  type: "Writable Node",
                  shape: "Rectangle",
                  text: "Write here",
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  notes: ""
              },
              {
                  key: "roundTable",
                  color: "#ffffff",
                  stroke: '#000000',
                  caption: "Round Table",
                  type: "Round Table",
                  shape: "Ellipse",
                  width: 61,
                  height: 61,
                  notes: ""
              },
              {
                  key: "armChair",
                  color: "#ffffff",
                  stroke: '#000000',
                  caption: "Arm Chair",
                  type: "Arm Chair",
                  geo: "F1 M0 0 L40 0 40 40 0 40 0 0 M10 30 L10 10 M0 0 Q8 0 10 10 M0 40 Q20 15 40 40 M30 10 Q32 0 40 0 M30 10 L30 30",
                  width: 45,
                  height: 45,
                  notes: ""
              },
              {
                  key: "sofaMedium",
                  color: "#ffffff",
                  stroke: "#000000",
                  caption: "Sofa",
                  type: "Sofa",
                  geo: "F1 M0 0 L80 0 80 40 0 40 0 0 M10 35 L10 10 M0 0 Q8 0 10 10 M0 40 Q40 15 80 40 M70 10 Q72 0 80 0 M70 10 L70 35",
                  height: 45,
                  width: 90,
                  notes: ""
              },
              {
                  key: "sink",
                  color: "#ffffff",
                  stroke: '#000000',
                  caption: "Sink",
                  type: "Sink",
                  geo: "F1 M0 0 L40 0 40 40 0 40 0 0z M5 7.5 L18.5 7.5 M 21.5 7.5 L35 7.5 35 35 5 35 5 7.5 M 15 21.25 A 5 5 180 1 0 15 21.24 M23 3.75 A 3 3 180 1 1 23 3.74 M21.5 6.25 L 21.5 12.5 18.5 12.5 18.5 6.25 M15 3.75 A 1 1 180 1 1 15 3.74 M 10 4.25 L 10 3.25 13 3.25 M 13 4.25 L 10 4.25 M27 3.75 A 1 1 180 1 1 27 3.74 M 26.85 3.25 L 30 3.25 30 4.25 M 26.85 4.25 L 30 4.25",
                  width: 27,
                  height: 27,
                  notes: ""
              },
              {
                  key: "doubleSink",
                  color: "#ffffff",
                  stroke: '#000000',
                  caption: "Double Sink",
                  type: "Double Sink",
                  geo: "F1 M0 0 L75 0 75 40 0 40 0 0 M5 7.5 L35 7.5 35 35 5 35 5 7.5 M44 7.5 L70 7.5 70 35 40 35 40 9 M15 21.25 A5 5 180 1 0 15 21.24 M50 21.25 A 5 5 180 1 0 50 21.24 M40.5 3.75 A3 3 180 1 1 40.5 3.74 M40.5 3.75 L50.5 13.75 47.5 16.5 37.5 6.75 M32.5 3.75 A 1 1 180 1 1 32.5 3.74 M 27.5 4.25 L 27.5 3.25 30.5 3.25 M 30.5 4.25 L 27.5 4.25 M44.5 3.75 A 1 1 180 1 1 44.5 3.74 M 44.35 3.25 L 47.5 3.25 47.5 4.25 M 44.35 4.25 L 47.5 4.25",
                  height: 27,
                  width: 52,
                  notes: ""
              },
              {
                  key: "toilet",
                  color: "#ffffff",
                  stroke: '#000000',
                  caption: "Toilet",
                  type: "Toilet",
                  geo: "F1 M0 0 L25 0 25 10 0 10 0 0 M20 10 L20 15 5 15 5 10 20 10 M5 15 Q0 15 0 25 Q0 40 12.5 40 Q25 40 25 25 Q25 15 20 15",
                  width: 25,
                  height: 35,
                  notes: ""
              },
              {
                  key: "shower",
                  color: "#ffffff",
                  stroke: '#000000',
                  caption: "Shower/Tub",
                  type: "Shower/Tub",
                  geo: "F1 M0 0 L40 0 40 60 0 60 0 0 M35 15 L35 55 5 55 5 15 Q5 5 20 5 Q35 5 35 15 M22.5 20 A2.5 2.5 180 1 1 22.5 19.99",
                  width: 45,
                  height: 75,
                  notes: ""
              },
              {
                  key: "bed",
                  color: "#ffffff",
                  stroke: '#000000',
                  caption: "Bed",
                  type: "Bed",
                  geo: "F1 M0 0 L40 0 40 60 0 60 0 0 M 7.5 2.5 L32.5 2.5 32.5 17.5 7.5 17.5 7.5 2.5 M0 20 L40 20 M0 25 L40 25",
                  width: 76.2,
                  height: 101.6,
                  notes: ""
              },
              {
                  key: "staircase",
                  color: "#ffffff",
                  stroke: '#000000',
                  caption: "Staircase",
                  type: "Staircase",
                  geo: "F1 M0 0 L 0 100 250 100 250 0 0 0 M25 100 L 25 0 M 50 100 L 50 0 M 75 100 L 75 0 M 100 100 L 100 0 M 125 100 L 125 0 M 150 100 L 150 0 M 175 100 L 175 0 M 200 100 L 200 0 M 225 100 L 225 0",
                  width: 125,
                  height: 50,
                  notes: ""
              },
              {
                  key: "stove",
                  color: "#ffffff",
                  stroke: '#000000',
                  caption: "Stove",
                  type: "Stove",
                  geo: "F1 M 0 0 L 0 100 100 100 100 0 0 0 M 30 15 A 15 15 180 1 0 30.01 15 M 70 15 A 15 15 180 1 0 70.01 15"
                  + "M 30 55 A 15 15 180 1 0 30.01 55 M 70 55 A 15 15 180 1 0 70.01 55",
                  width: 75,
                  height: 75,
                  notes: ""
              },
              {
                  key: "diningTable",
                  color: "#ffffff",
                  stroke: '#000000',
                  caption: "Dining Table",
                  type: "Dining Table",
                  geo: "F1 M 0 0 L 0 100 200 100 200 0 0 0 M 25 0 L 25 -10 75 -10 75 0 M 125 0 L 125 -10 175 -10 175 0 M 200 25 L 210 25 210 75 200 75 M 125 100 L 125 110 L 175 110 L 175 100 M 25 100 L 25 110 75 110 75 100 M 0 75 -10 75 -10 25 0 25",
                  width: 125,
                  height: 62.5,
                  notes: ""
              }
];
```

i searched a lot for "geo" but i didnt found any thing so how to draw a new one is there any video or tutorials for this?

**Another Question**
How can i remove the default text in the top left:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I am the developer who built this sample.

First, you may be interested in Floorplanner version 2, which can be found [here](https://gojs.net/latest/projects/floorplannerTS/floorplannerTSSample.html)

If you want to create your own shapes for furniture nodes, you will have to add a new entry to the nodeDataArray of the furniturePalette, and specify the "geo" property accordingly. The "geo" property is a custom data property that is bound to the "geometryString" property of furniture Nodes. It is a formatted geometry string, which you can learn more about here: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/geometry.html

If you do not understand data bindings, you should read about them here: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/dataBinding.html

Removing or changing the text of the Palettes window handle is as simple as modifying the HTML file contents.

Comment: Hi Ryan .. I would like to thank you for your response, i found that the paths on the "geo" property is just a svg paths so its not a big deal but i would like to ask you if it possible to make chairs on each table be dynamic like this image in our old system (https://imgur.com/sY8BHus) the number of chairs increases when click on plus and vice versa. In this example we used Fabricjs but we faced a lot of problems on it, if it not possible in gojs, did you know any other libraries can help us to do this point.. Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose it is possible with GoJS, though it will require some work, as well as some decisions regarding how "chairs" are added, where they are added, what happens when there is no more space at the "table" and so on. Without getting too deep into it, you could have a button as part of the selectionAdornmentTemplate for a Node that, when clicked, adds a "chair" to the Node (perhaps this could just be a go.Shape element in the nodeTemplate). Of course, if you want this to persist, you'd need to save it to model data.
https://gojs.net/latest/samples/adornmentButtons.html

Comment: It seems that this will not work in our case, but I want to ask you the last question, when i try to add a new shape to the palette it looks like without background and cant change its color or handle it ad all, you can see the problem clearly in this video (https://www.loom.com/share/95bd404e747b4b03adef8812fbb59660) it happened when i use svg or even geometry path for the image, it seems like something missing in my code and i cant get it can you help me with the right way to include a new image to palette because the link you put above is not clear and Thank you again